# Where and what is the error in the code below and how to correct it?

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

The equations used in the following code are given as a standard and assumed to be true for all real numbers. The console is showing a

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'.

```
 import math as m
 def theta_m(i):
 a=3
 delta_t=1
 b=3
 if i==0:
    return m.pi/6
else:
     y=theta_m(i-1)+a*(beta(i)-beta(i-1))+delta_t*b*m.sin((beta(i-1)- theta_m(i-1)))
    return y

def beta(i):
n=3
delta_t=1
theta_t=0
if i==0:
    return 1.0/20.0
else:
    y=beta(i-1)+(delta_t*(-m.sin(beta(i-1)-theta_t)+n*m.sin(beta(i-1)-theta_m(i-1))))/r(i-1)
return y

def r(i):
n=3
theta_t=0
delta_t=1
if i==0:
    return 1
else:
    y=r(i-1)+delta_t*(m.cos(beta(i-1)-theta_t)-n*(m.cos(beta(i-1)-theta_m(i-1))))

    if y>1.5:
            print "The missile will not hit the target"

    else:
        print" keep trying"
```

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly.

Comment: You should indent the code correctly here in the post, not at home where noone can access it. Also, your problem is not reproducible, since you did not say which function to call using which parameter `i`. Finally, I think even when the code is correct, you will have problems, because for certain parameters your code will run forever (producing maximum recursion error).